# Upload multiple images with file input to canvas elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, canvas

I create multiple canvas elements along with an input file element through some Javascript code.

And I want the image that I upload with a input is loaded by the canvas element but I'm struggling.

```
function addMoreFileUploads(id){
    $("#fileUploads").append('<input id="' + id + '" type="file" name="files[]" OnChange="handleImage()" /> <br><br>');
    var imageLoader = document.getElementById(id);
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
}

function createVariables(){

    $('#canvasInsert').empty();

    alert('variable time');
    idArray.forEach(function (entry){
        var canvasName =  'canvas' + entry;
        $("#canvasInsert").append('<canvas id="'+ canvasName +'" style="border:1px solid #000000;" width="500" height="500"></canvas>');
    });
}
```

This is some of the code I'm using. The top method adds the input file field, and I then create canvas elements afterwards matching the names of the input elements. I'm just not sure how to make the canvas element load the image from the corresponding file input.

I'm really not sure how to carry on, still a beginner to Javascript.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement handleimage function like that:

```
function handleImage(e) {

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(event) {

                var thisimage = new Image();
                thisimage.onload = function() {
                };
                thisimage.src = event.target.result;


            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
```

}

Then you can assign thisimage.src to canvas. Adopt it in your loop to have each canvas load corresponding image